# MySql exibir a soma campo com valor null

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Já pesquisei mas nada encontro do que preciso.

Tenho uma tabela onde tenho o registro de lançamentos de débitos e créditos.
Esses valores estão no campo 'valor'.
Mas quero exibir esse campo em duas colunas, uma para débito e outra para crédito.

Consegui:

```
SELECT L.REGISTRO, C.CODCADASTRO, CRE.VALOR AS CREDITO, DEB.VALOR AS DEBITO 
   FROM CADASTRO C 
      JOIN LANCAMENTOS L ON C.CODCADASTRO = L.CODFAVORECIDO       
      LEFT JOIN LANCAMENTOS CRE ON CRE.REGISTRO = L.REGISTRO AND CRE.TIPOLANCAMENTO = 0
      LEFT JOIN LANCAMENTOS DEB ON DEB.REGISTRO = L.REGISTRO AND DEB.TIPOLANCAMENTO = 1
```

Quero acrescentar mais uma coluna para somar as duas e é aí que não consigo. A coluna que tem o débito fico com NULL no crédito e o mesmo acontece com a coluna do crédito. A soma dos registros dessas colunas está vindo NULL.

```
CRE.VALOR AS CREDITO, DEB.VALOR AS DEBITO, (CRE.VALOR + DEB.VALOR) AS SOMA
```

Então meu problema é: Como somar os valores dos campos por registro onde um campo é NULL?

Att.

Comment: Você quer somar um valor com NULL? tipo 1+null??

Comment: Sim, isso porque um LEFT JOIN gerou um valor NULL numas das colunas e eu não estava conseguindo efetuar as somas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `COALESCE` serve bem para isso:

```
CRE.VALOR AS CREDITO, DEB.VALOR AS DEBITO,
  ( COALESCE( CRE.VALOR, 0 ) + COALESCE( DEB.VALOR, 0 ) ) AS SOMA
```

A sintaxe é:

```
COALESCE( v1, v2, v3, ... )
```

Basicamente essa função faz com que seja usado o primeiro valor da lista que não seja nulo.

Exemplos:

```
SELECT COALESCE( null, 2, null, 4 )             => 2
SELECT COALESCE( null, null, null, 'a' )        => 'a'
SELECT COALESCE( 1, 2, 3, 4 )                   => 1

SELECT COALESCE( 1, 2 ) + COALESCE( 4, 8 )      => 5
SELECT COALESCE( null, 2 ) + COALESCE( 4, 8 )   => 6
SELECT COALESCE( 1, 2 ) + COALESCE( null, 8 )   => 9
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/54463)**.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu precisava.

Comment: Se precisar, pode usar para agregação também: `SELECT SUM( COALESCE( DEB.VALOR, 0 ) ) AS TOTALGERAL`

Comment: Essa tabela é um extrato bancário. Meu próximo passo é fazer a atualização do saldo, para isso, nessa coluna soma, tenho que pegar o valor da linha anterior e somar com a linha atual e exibir a soma na coluna SALDO. Mas devo fazer dentro do programa, pois o registro zero é o saldo inicial do extrato.

Comment: Dá pra fazer com _queries_ também, somando o valor anterior como uma constante. De qualquer forma, tem casos em que é melhor tratar na aplicação mesmo.